# Embed AngularJS application to another application

Tags: angularjs

I have two AngularJS applications say app1 and app2. I want to embed app2 in app1. My requirement is that I should be able to import a single script file from app2 to app1 and able to embed app2 in app1.

Comment: can you inject it? `angular.module('app1', ['app2'])`

Comment: No, I am not able to do that.